# How to upload large folders to onedrive

Tags: hard-drive, onedrive

I have a 500GB external drive full of data. I need to use this drive so, since I have 1TB of storage in OneDrive, I want to uploaded the content to free up the drive. I have a quite good connection too, so I figured it wouldn't take too long. The thing is that I can't find a way to upload this folder with the OneDrive Windows app.

Looking online, everyone proposed to move folders to my computer and then upload it, but that isn't an option since I don't have enough space in it. The other option is using the web app, but it is very unreliable and will stop working more often than not. Besides, if it stops, the upload has to start from the beginning.

Comment: You could use the web app and move it in chunks so that if it does fail you don't have to start all over, you only have to restart that chunk. This would take more user interaction on your part but unless you move it to your local machine, it sounds like that's your best option.

Comment: What exactly are you doing and what is the error message?

Comment: Have you consulted OneDrive support? https://support.office.com/en-us/home/chat?ContactUsExperienceEntryPointAssetId=S.HP.onedrive&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.office.com%2Fen-us%2Fonedrive

Comment: I'd just get an extra drive instead of all that hassle.

Answer (score 0):

- Download the [open source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/7-Zip) [7-Zip for Windows](https://www.7-zip.org/) freeware and install it.
- Start it in its file manager mode (7z.exe, not 7za.exe from the command line)
- Create an archive file of selected content [under 20GB in size](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/fix-problems-uploading-files-on-the-onedrive-website-9afcc4a0-e344-4bc9-9c9d-59d3e802247e) from that external drive.
- Upload that archive from a current version of a web browser or using the Windows OneDrive app. Remember, OneDrive will fail when you exceed 20GB in your uploaded file if using a web browser.
- Download it.
- Use [FC](https://ss64.com/nt/fc.html) (a native Windows app) to verify the download matches the original file, a la `FC /B ORIGINAL.7Z DOWNLOADED.7Z`
- When it verifies, delete ORIGINAL.7Z and DOWNLOADED.7Z both.
- Repeat the process until the entire drive's content has been uploaded, downloaded, verified, and deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You may be running into the 20GB OneDrive upload limit.
Divide the files into manageable folders, and make compressed archives of those folders. You can file folders inside other folders.  Use a visualizer like https://windirstat.net/ to identify which folders you need to break into sub-folders.

When you have a folder between 19-20 GB, run it through a compression program like WinZip, 7Zip, or WinRAR.  Understand that many file types like video and jpg will not compress much.  Understand that different OSes count binary versus decimal GB differently.

Upload the individual folders to OneDrive.

External Hard Drives are cheap in 2018.  For $200, you can get a 10 TB drive that will be reasonably reliable for years.